# rownames() in R: why not working with paste0()?

Tags: r, matrix

I was wondering why `rownames()` doesn't correctly work in my below R code?

```
revenue = c(15,18,22,23,24, 22,25,15,15,14, 18,22,15,19,21, 
            23,15,14,17,18, 23,15,26,18,14, 12,15,11,10,8, 26,12,23,15,18, 
            19,17,15,20,10, 15,14,18,19,20, 14,18,10,12,23, 14,22,19,17,11, 
            21,23,11,18,14)

months = gl(12, 5)

years = gl(5, 1, length(revenue))

m = matrix(c(revenue,  years, months), nrow = 60,  ncol = 3)

rownames(m) = list(paste0("subj ", 1:60))   ### Why rownames() doesn't work? ###
```

Comment: Very minor detail, but why use `paste( "subj", 1:60 )` rather than paste0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is to just let the nature of R do the work for you as it  will iterate through paste and assign names.

`row.names(m) <- paste0("subj " , 1:60)`

It calls the least functions and gets the job done,

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `list`, but `rownames` accepts a vector. Use this instead:

```
rownames(m) = paste0("subj ", 1:60)
```

Comment: Or use nothing instead